# Deduce the array-sizes in a variadic template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

I try to write a `constexpr` function that accepts a variable number of C-Strings. And I want to deduce all of the sizes (here: `L0` and `LL`) of the passed arrays. Looks like a stupid error I make there, but trying to do so, I get an error:

```
error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
  204 | constexpr auto generate(const char (&s0)[L0], const char (&ss)[LL] ...) {
```

```
template<size_t L0, size_t... LL>
constexpr auto generate(const char (&s0)[L0], const char (&ss)[LL] ...) {
    constexpr size_t ll = (LL + ...);
    std::integral_constant<size_t, L0>::_;
    std::integral_constant<size_t, ll>::_;
        
    std::array<char, 1 + L0 + ll> r;
    return r;        
}

constexpr auto STR_X = generate("abc", "def");
```

This is done with `gcc` version 12.0 and `-std=c++20`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem should be the expansion of `ss` (that is variadic too)

```
// ellipsis here ...........................................VVV
constexpr auto generate(const char (&s0)[L0], const char (& ... ss)[LL]) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make the function simpler by avoiding over-specification of the parameter type. Furthermore, since the first parameter isn't treated differently from the rest, it seems unnecessary:

```
constexpr auto
generate(auto&&... ss) {
    constexpr size_t ll = (sizeof(ss) + ...);
    return std::array<char, 1 + ll>{};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the **ellipsis** `...` at the wrong place. The correction is shown below:

```
template<size_t L0, size_t... LL>
constexpr auto generate(const char (&s0)[L0], const char (&...ss)[LL]) {
                                                         //^^^
    
         
}
```